# SSIS-Calling java service using Script Task

Tags: sql-server, web-services, ssis, etl, script-task

I am trying to call a java base web service method writing following code in script task's entry point method. Following code get executing properly if i call from console application but while calling from SSIS control flow, upto message box 1 it get executed properly but on executing  webRequest.GetResponse() what happen dont know neither it gives error nor it execute next line of code.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string envelopeContent = GetSoapEvvelope();
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(envelopeContent);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST"; // get executed
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        MessageBox.Show("1"); 
        WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
        MessageBox.Show("2"); // does not get executed
        string responseString = string.Empty;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(responseString);
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='result']");
       }
```

Please guide me what to do? As per my understanding web service task require WSDL/proxy. Is there any other way to call java base web service passing soap envelope in request?

Thanks

@paul

Comment: Can you check the web server receiving the requests and see if it  is being called? Are you running this interactively in BIDS and you only see one message box 1 and no more? The Java part should be irrelevant, it's just a web service.

Comment: Yes i'm running it from BIDS and i can see only  msg box 1. As per fiddler server get request. Fiddler info as bellow - The selected session is a HTTP CONNECT Tunnel. This tunnel enables a client to send raw traffic (e.g. HTTPS-encrypted streams or WebSocket messages) through a HTTP Proxy Server (like Fiddler).

Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      97  (headers:97; body:0)
Bytes Received:  107  (headers:107; body:0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this while using sql server 2008 R2. Now i have tried same solution in sql server 2012 and it is working fine with out any changes.